# How to make two tables horizontal on the same like in html

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Hello I am trying to make two tables (one with an image) horizontal on the same line. I want it to be so when the screen changes to mobile, the table on the left goes on top of the right one vertically.

```
  <table style="display: inline-block" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                       border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top"
                                            style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
                                            <img src="#"
                                                 style=" height: auto; display: block; border: 0;">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>


                                        <table style="display: inline-block" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                               border="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"
                                            style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
                                            <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height:20px; color:#043667; margin:10px 0; font-family: Arial, Narrow, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                                <span style="color: #9d0059; font-weight: bold">text1,</span> text 2”
                                                <br><span style="color: #9d0059"><i>-HAEGARDA Advocate</i></span>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to get rid of the `width:100%`, otherwise two of them won't fit side by side in the same line!

Also, I'd use `display:inline-table` rather than `display:inline-block`.

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0;
}

th,td {
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
      <img src="#" style=" height: auto; display: block; border: 0;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
      <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height:20px; color:#043667; margin:10px 0; font-family: Arial, Narrow, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <span style="color: #9d0059; font-weight: bold">text1,</span> text 2”
        <br><span style="color: #9d0059"><i>-HAEGARDA Advocate</i></span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made the edits but it seems that the tables are still stacking on top of one another.

Comment: Do I need to nest these tables in to a parent table?

Comment: It looks like it's working from here - the tables are side by side, until I make the window narrower, then the right one drops down to below the left one. Did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I misunderstood. It worked perfectly and you had an excellent explanation. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flexbox layout to accomplish that. Firstly, you can put both tables inside a `div` and set the div `display` property to `flex` (style="display: flex;"). This will put both tables in-line with each other.

To make them stack vertically on mobile or smaller devices, you can set the `div` `flex-wrap` property to `wrap`. This will cause the tables to stack vertically. Check the code below, most importantly the `div` tag.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
        <img src="#" style=" height: auto; display: block; border: 0;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-bottom: 0">
        <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height:20px; color:#043667; margin:10px 0; font-family: Arial, Narrow, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <span style="color: #9d0059; font-weight: bold">text1,</span> text 2”
          <br><span style="color: #9d0059"><i>-HAEGARDA Advocate</i></span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```